# Vue doesn't update when data changes

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I have a page that I call like *domain.com/subpage?soundfile=something*

In my fetch method I use the query from the url to actually fetch the data. The query works, I'm getting the data and I'm assigning it to *this.recording* which also works, according to the *console.log*. However, neither my span nor my audio element ever update. Why?

```
<template>
  <div>
    <audio controls>
      <source :key="key" :src="recording" type="audio/mp3" />
    </audio>
    <span :key="key">{{ recording }}</span>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
const axios = require("axios").default;

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      key: 0,
      recording: ""
    };
  },
  async fetch(context) {
    const ip = await axios.get(
      "somebackend/?soundfile=" + context.query.soundfile
    );

    this.recording = ip.data[0].file.url;
    console.log(this.recording); // gives me the correct url/mp3 file
    this.key++; // should update the audio element and the span but doesn't
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: what's the significance of the `key` attribute on a `<source>` element? and how is that `fetch` being called? I get the feeling `this` isn't what you expect it to be

Comment: when it didn't update I added a key, thinking it might update when I change the key. last line of the fetch function. doesn't work though.

Comment: you forgot to answer *how is `fetch` called*? I think that's the key - normally, such functions are created as `methods` or executed inside a `mounted` or `created` etc ... but the way you've written it, makes no sense in vue - i.e. ` fetch` property on a vue component - can't see that documented anywhere

Comment: [nuxt docs](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/internals-glossary/context)
it gets called automatically, just like asyncData, which I ended up using

Comment: Oh, you never mentioned nuxt

Comment: Ah, sorry! I thought I had it in my tags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working version:
Had to use asyncData instead of fetch.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <audio controls>
      <source :src="soundfile" type="audio/mp3" />
    </audio>
    <span>{{ soundfile }}</span>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
const axios = require("axios").default;

export default {
  async asyncData(context) {
    const ip = await axios.get(
      "somebackend/?soundfile=" + context.query.soundfile
    );

    return {
      soundfile: ip.data[0].file.url
    };
  }
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell the audio tag that the load is complete.

If you don't know nuxt well, but say it's similar to vue
Whenever this.recording changes using watch, you can run .load() on the aduio tag.

for example.

```
<audio controls ref='player'>
```

```
this.$watch('record', () => {
                this.$refs.player.load()
            })
```

Answer (score -1):

I think one major thing you missed out on was adding the methods block:

```
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      key: 0,
      recording: ""
    };
  },
  methods: {
    async fetch(context) {
      const ip = await axios.get(
        "somebackend/?soundfile=" + context.query.soundfile
      );
      this.recording = ip.data[0].file.url;
      console.log(this.recording); // gives me the correct url/mp3 file
      this.key++; // should update the audio element and the span but doesn't
    }
  },
};
</script>
```

Since its not in the methods block, the reference to `this` is not what you are expecting i.e. the vue instance. Hence, the key is not updating and it gets logged to the console but since its not bound to the vue instance, changes do not reflect in the template.

Regards

Comment: If I put it in the methods block it won't get called automatically. I need access to the context in order to get the part after the ? in the url. [nuxt docs](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/internals-glossary/context)
But reading to the docs again made me realize I can use asyncData instead of fetch, that works.

Comment: You can use the `beforeMount` or `mounted` lifecycle hooks to call that method.

Comment: I'm not sure I get the context object if I call it as a normal method. But like I said, just switching fetch for asyncData works. No need for a method in the method block.

Comment: @Dhwanilshah - OP forgot to mention he's using nuxt - that minor detail changes the complexion of the whole question

Comment: @dan No worries.

Comment: `fetch()` is a own hook in nuxt so this wont help him

Comment: @Ifaruki This answer was provided without the info that Dan was using nuxt.